# Convert string to in array python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a an string and I need to get it into a format where I can iterate trough it:

`[["","","",""],["","2","",""],["","","",""],["2","","",""]]`

Can anyone help.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Show some code, input and expected output. What have you tried so far? SO is not a code factory to write your code for you... Please REALLY look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list inside that string, you can just use json to load its content:

```
import json


list_ = json.loads('[["","","",""],["","2","",""],["","","",""],["2","","",""]]')
```

And then you can iterate over `list_` as you please

Comment: Thank You This Has Solved My Problem. For some reason I did not think to do tat even though that was the original format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your asking exactly, but if you want to find the index in which "2" is located you can do this, otherwise pls elaborate:

```
storeString = [["","","",""],["","2","",""],["","","",""],["2","","",""]]

for i in storeString:
   if "2" in i:
     print(i.index("2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way you can do it is:

```
my_list = [["", "", "", ""], ["", "2", "", ""], ["", "", "", ""], ["2", "", "", ""]]
my_new_list = []

for a_list in my_list:
    my_new_list.extend(a_list)

for item in my_new_list:
    print(item)
```

And the output will be:

```
2






2
```

You can iterate the list and use `append` instead of using `extend`:

```
my_list = [["", "", "", ""], ["", "2", "", ""], ["", "", "", ""], ["2", "", "", ""]]
my_new_list = []

for a_list in my_list:
    for item in a_list:
        my_new_list.append(item)

for item in my_new_list:
    print(item)
```

And the output will be the same.

And as The Zach Man mentioned, you can see more examples [here (How to make a flat list out of list of lists?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)